# Writing ASP.NET code within an ASP literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am writing an application that will display database queries. There are different tables and I would like to be able to choose between them with radio buttons. This is currently working properly, but now I am trying to figure out how to format the data repeater based on which table will be displayed (there are different numbers of columns, in a different order, etc.) I got the header to format successfully since it is just basic HTML, but the item template requires using asp inline code, which I believe is causing the problem.

relevant code from code-behind:

```
protected string showDataTableItemTemplate()
{
    string itemTemplateText = string.Empty;

    if (tableSelection == "parts")
    {
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.PartNumber\") %></td>";
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";

    }
    else if (tableSelection == "package")
    {
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.PackageNumber\") %></td>";
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";

    }
    else if (tableSelection == "product")
    {
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.ProductNumber\") %></td>";
        itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";
    }
    return itemTemplateText;
}
```

Then I just have the literal defined like this in the aspx:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#showDataTableItemTemplate() %>'></asp:Literal>
```

Is there another way to do this?

EDIT: I now have the following:

```
    protected void DataRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        LiteralControl itemTemplateLiteral = new LiteralControl();
        itemTemplateLiteral = (LiteralControl)FindControl("itemTemplate");
        string itemTemplateText = string.Empty;

        if (tableSelection == "parts")
        {
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.PartNumber\") %></td>";
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";

        }
        else if (tableSelection == "package")
        {
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.PackageNumber\") %></td>";
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";

        }
        else if (tableSelection == "product")
        {
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.ProductNumber\") %></td>";
            itemTemplateText += "<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,\"DataItem.Description\") %></td>";

        }
        itemTemplateLiteral.Text = itemTemplateText;
    }
```

The compiler keeps telling me that there is an *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* error. Also, Am I correct in trying to set the Text property still? (Wasn't that what I was trying to avoid by using this method?)

Comment: Use `switch(tableSelection)` instead of nested `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an event handler for the `OnItemDataBound` event of the template control and in it use `FindControl` to locate the `Literal` control and assign values to it using the `e.Item.DataItem`.

What your current code is doing is simply assigning strings to the literal - these will not be evaluated as part of page markup because they are *not* part of the markup.

Comment: What is the difference between 'OnDataBind' and 'OnItemDataBound'? Do I need to use the latter since this occurs for each piece of data?

Comment: @Kyle - Sorry, I did mean `OnItemDataBound`.

Comment: Ok, so I created the `OnItemDataBound` (and the `OnDataBind` as well just in case I need it.) I declared a Control type variable `Control itemTemplateLiteral = FindControl("itemTemplateText");` Is this correct? when I try e. the only methods are `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `ToString`, and `GetType`

Comment: Ok, i figured that last part out. I was using the standard `EventArgs` rather than the `RepeaterItemEventArgs`
Now, how to assign values using the dataItem

Comment: @Kyle - You need to cast the `Control` returned by `FindControl` to the correct type (in this case `LiteralControl`): `var itemTemplateLiteral = (LiteralControl)FindControl("itemTemplateText");`

Answer (score 2):

Bind the OnItemDataBound event, find the controls in the page and assign their values directly. Like so:

```
    protected void datalist1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            // fetch values from the data bound row
            int identityID = e.Item.DataItem["columnname"];

            // Find your page control and assign values
            HtmlAnchor aBlogSbj = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("aBlogSbj");
            if (aBlogSbj != null)
            {
                aBlogSbj.HRef=identityID;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok, I'm really not familiar with this web controls stuff...

I want to display multiple columns in each row, and the code that calls those columns (the DataItem.Eval(Container, "columnname") ) changes based upon some user input. I can't seem to put things together